# The Progressive CPU lightmapper is not supported on Apple silicon

Tags: flutter, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I want to do a flutter-unity project using AR. When I made the unity AR project, this message showed up:

The Progressive CPU lightmapper is not supported on Apple silicon, switching to the Progressive GPU lightmapper.

I do not know what to do I have to do an AR project with unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're developing on an M1 Mac (which I assume you are since you're getting this message), and targeting an M1 Mac, then I don't think you have to do anything (but you can take @YudReish's suggestion to turn off the warning).

If you're not targeting an M1, then be sure to install the appropriate platform support. When you build the proper Lightmapper should be installed.

Answer (score 3):

Open Lighting window (in Unity menu Window->Rendering->Lighting).

In "Scene" tab, "Lightmapping Setting" section, switch "Lightmapper" to "Progressive GPU" (may show that its still in Preview).

Close window and you're set.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your answer is the opposite of what OP is asking for. OP is asking for CPU, not GPU.

Comment: @lepsch do have any idea?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Sorry